# How to encode and compress captured video to mp4 format like Viddy app?

Tags: iphone, video, mp4

How to encode and compress captured video to mp4 format like Viddy app? any suggestion and tutorials is appreciative.

Comment: Check SO: How can I convert mov to mp4 on ios device: short answer is maybe you dont need to do this.. test before doing hard work http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12548304/how-can-i-convert-mov-to-mp4-on-ios-device