# how to play .mov format video file in android application

Tags: android, video, mov

I am developing an android application which plays videos from our server uploaded by both iphone and android, and the problem is that the videos recorded by iphone is in .mov format, which is not supported by android. I searched a lot, but couldn't found any solution. Help me out. Thanks in advance  :)

Comment: take a look here :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12548304/how-can-i-convert-mov-to-mp4-on-ios-device

Comment: convert your video into a format which is recognised by Android. Serve the mov to iPhone, and whichever format you decide upon to Android.

Comment: Or use the **mp4** format, which is played by both Android and the iPhone.

Comment: transcode the video, that best way.  if you have enough processing power, on the fly transcoding is another way

Answer (score 0):

I will recomend you to change the format from the iphones to a compatible (even open will be better), because 2 differents formats of videos on server soon or later will be a headache.

If you could, reformat your videos with [ffmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/) and save it all with the same format on server.

If you can't or it's really hard to achieve, you could try the ExoPlayer component from Google.
I have tried on an app like you, where devices (iPhone and Android) record videos and upload to the server.
Reformatting all this video on server side will be almost impossible so we endly make the decission to apply a solution on client side for legacy videos.

https://google.github.io/ExoPlayer/

The setup from ExoPlayer it's larger than VideoView, but it's simple to be done.

```
    private var player: ExoPlayer = initPlayer()

    private fun initPlayer(): ExoPlayer {
        val bandwidthMeter = DefaultBandwidthMeter()
        val videoTrackSelectionFactory = AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory(bandwidthMeter)
        val trackSelector = DefaultTrackSelector(videoTrackSelectionFactory)
        return ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(context, trackSelector)
    }

fun setup() {

        videoExo.setPlayer(player)
        videoExo.useController = false

        val dataSourceFactory = DefaultDataSourceFactory(
            context,
            Util.getUserAgent(context, context?.packageName), DefaultBandwidthMeter()
        )

        val videoSource = ExtractorMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory).createMediaSource(videoUri)

        player.addListener(object: Player.EventListener {
            override fun onPlayerStateChanged(playWhenReady: Boolean, playbackState: Int) {
                if (playbackState == Player.STATE_READY) {
                    startCallback()
                }
            }
            override fun onPlaybackParametersChanged(playbackParameters: PlaybackParameters?) {}
            override fun onSeekProcessed() {}
            override fun onTracksChanged(trackGroups: TrackGroupArray?, trackSelections: TrackSelectionArray?) {}
            override fun onPlayerError(error: ExoPlaybackException?) {}
            override fun onLoadingChanged(isLoading: Boolean) {}
            override fun onPositionDiscontinuity(reason: Int) {}
            override fun onRepeatModeChanged(repeatMode: Int) {}
            override fun onShuffleModeEnabledChanged(shuffleModeEnabled: Boolean) {}
            override fun onTimelineChanged(timeline: Timeline?, manifest: Any?, reason: Int) {}
        })

        player.prepare(videoSource)
        player.playWhenReady = true
        player.repeatMode = REPEAT_MODE_ALL

    }
```

Hope this helps