# Change video format .mov to .mp4 in ios6

Tags: iphone, uiimagepickercontroller, video-capture, mp4

I want to convert .mov to .mp4 . When I record video from an iPhone camera, it automatically records video using the .mov format which is not able to play on android OS. I want to convert this format to .mp4 so the video will easily play on both iPhone and Android.
I have converted video formats by using the following code:

```
[request addData:videoData withFileName:@"video1.mp4" andContentType:@"video/mp4" forKey:@"video"];
```

Now the format is changed but it does not run on the android device.

Comment: You are not changing to the format at all. You are just upload the `mov` file with the name `video1.mp4` and telling the server that the type is `video/mp4`.

Comment: Than how i convert this format in to mp4 , by this that video convert in both device.

Comment: Please! check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8474517/mov-to-mp4-video-conversion-iphone-programmatically) may help you

Comment: you just have to save your mov video with mp4 format to make it work.. [for more ref see this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12548304/how-can-i-convert-mov-to-mp4-on-ios-device)