# .mp4 file uploaded from react-native won't play in chrome

Tags: video, mp4, mov

I have a situation where I am recorded a video via expo / react-native and uploaded it to a s3 bucket. However, when I access the s3 link in the browser, the video will not play. However, the video will play in VLC media player if i download it first. I'm not sure why the video won't play in chrome (or any other browser). The expected behavior is the link will play in the browser.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Record video via react-native (this will save the video as a .mov file)
2. "Convert" the file to .mp4 by using Expo's FileSystem.moveAsync() to rename the file to .mp4
3. Upload to s3 (with mime type video/mp4)
4. Open the s3 link in the browser:

[image]

However, if I download the video an open it in VLC, it will play fine. Does anyone know what's going on?

Note - I was inspired by this SO to convert .mov to .mp4 by simply changing the file's extension [How can I convert mov to mp4 on ios device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12548304/how-can-i-convert-mov-to-mp4-on-ios-device/12589999#12589999)

Link to the file:
https://sandbox-of-sandboxes.s3.amazonaws.com/iKmlKprIs.mp4

Comment: Can you post a sample file?

Comment: yep @szatmary https://sandbox-of-sandboxes.s3.amazonaws.com/iKmlKprIs.mp4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The files is encoded using the HEVC codec. HEVC is not universally supported by all browser. You must covert the file to AVC/h.264

Comment: Hi, I am facing the same issue how so I convert the file to AVC/h.264?

Comment: Use any one of the hundreds of available video transcoding programs